# Removing ngRepeat item from $rootScope array doesn't instantly remove the item from html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to remove an *li* from a *ul* using angular, successfully removing the element from the array but angularJS doesn't remove the *li* until it is hovered over / some action is taken on that specific *li*. Code follows:

**app.js**

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, appAPIservice){ 
  appAPIservice.getInterests().success(function (response) {
    $rootScope.interests = [];
    if (response.data) {
      var interests = response.data;
      for (var i = 0; i < interests.length; i++) {
        $rootScope.interests.push(interests[i]));
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<ul ng-controller="interestsController">   
  <li ng-repeat="interest in interests">
    <a href="#{{interest.link}}">{{interest.parentName}} / {{interest.childName}}</a>
    <button ng-click="deleteInterest($index)"></button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**controllers.js**: deleteInterest is defined here

```
myApp.controller('interestsController', function($scope) {
  $scope.deleteInterest = function(arrayIndex) {
          $scope.interests.splice(arrayIndex, 1);
      });
  }
});
```

This produces the following output on page load:

```
<ul class="ng-scope" ng-controller="interestsController">   
  <li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="interest in interests">
    <a href="#/other-link class="ng-binding">Other Parent/Other Child</a>
    <button ng-click="deleteInterest($index)"><i class="icon-close"></i></button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem occurs when clicking deleteInterest() button. The following classes get added to the list item class: ng-animate, ng-leave, ng-leave-active. Unfortunately, the list item remains in the list **until the item is hovered over**. At that point, the list item is successfully removed from the DOM.

```
<li class="ng-scope ng-animate ng-leave ng-leave-active" ng-repeat="interest in interests">
  <a href="#/some-link" class="ng-binding">Some Parent / Some Child </a>
  <button ng-click="deleteInterest($index)"><i class="icon-close"></i></button>
</li>
```

I've tried wrapping the interestsController.deleteInterest's
`$scope.interests.splice(arrayIndex, 1);` line as

```
$scope.$apply(function(){ 
  $scope.interests.splice(arrayIndex, 1);
});
```

but I receive an error message saying that $scope.$digest is already in progress.

Is there a way to force angularJS to remove all ng-leave items?

Comment: Just curious, why use rootscope for this?

Comment: According with the previous comment, start bringing the api logics into the interestsController controller.

Those css classes that you see are useful when you need animations. Does your css implements some css animations? If yes you need to worry about those css classes, otherwise don't worry about them.

Comment: $scope.$apply doesn't make sense here, every bit of code you have here is within the angular digest cycle. That's why you are getting that error. Stop using $rootScope and put it in your controller/$scope. There's no need for you to put anything on $rootScope here nor use $scope.$apply.

Comment: @DanPantry we were using $rootScope because we display interests in a sidebar while also allowing for a user to click a "flag" on a page that would add that interest to the interests array in the sidebar. 

Since these are contained in different parts of the html, is there a way to call a controller in different places, ie. two different div structures ? As of right now, a directive is used for the interest-button flag, so I don't know how to call on the interestsController within that...

Comment: "is there a way to call a controller in different places" - a service?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas.  Instead of `$scope.$apply`, try

```
$timeout(function(){ 
  $scope.interests.splice(arrayIndex, 1);
});
```

$timeout will internaly trigger the digest if necessary, but won't throw that error if a digest is already in progress.

Alternatively, how about just using CSS to hide the li until angular gets round to removing it?

```
.ng-leave { display:none; }
```

Comment: The css change is a good workaround for how we have things structured, thank you. I still want to figure out why angular doesn't remove it on it's own after that gets applied. I've tried the timeout function to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with ng-repeat. 
After setting item array length to 0 I must run timeout with long delay:

```
$timeout(function(){ 
  do_some_action
}, 2000);
```

Even evalAsync doesn't work:

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function () {
   do_some_action
});
```

Another workaround is simply don't consider old items:

```
var elems = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('repeated_items'));
_.each(elems, function (itm) {
   if (itm.$$hashKey) return true;
   do_some_action
});
```